# mysql error missing parameter and string

Tags: php, mysql

I have an error in a mysql connection. It says `mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string on line 37`

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in
>   in folowing lines:

```
$result = mysql_query($link,"SELECT Name, id FROM skoleni WHERE Grupa = '".$_GET['grupa']."';");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: The $link is not required for mysql_query, this is if you are using mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT Name, id FROM skoleni WHERE Grupa = '".$_GET['grupa']."';");
```

No need of specifying connection parameter in mysql_query() function.
For further reference see this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

The $link is not required. Try this:

```
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT Name, id FROM skoleni WHERE Grupa = '".$_GET['grupa']."';");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Important:**

Stop using mysql_* api, its deprecated and generally bad. Use PDO or mysqli instead

Try

```
       $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT Name, id FROM skoleni WHERE Grupa = '".$_GET['grupa']."';");

       $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

     if ($rowcount > 0)
     {
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
         {
         }
     }
```

Comment: If you were going to post an example using mysqli, you could have at least used a prepared statement to avoid the obvious injection!